# Do all games that have Steam trading cards have foil trading cards?

Tags: steam-trading-cards

I'm looking into Steam trading cards and was wondering if all games that have Steam trading cards have foil trading cards?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if all games has it, but you can check it by if that game has a [foil badge](https://steamtradingcards.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Foil_Badges) (Though, by the explanation on that page, `In addition to the 5 levels of the standard badge, each trading card set has a foil badge`, I guess all of the games has foil badge, therefore all of the games has its foil cards.)

For Example, CS:GO has a badge called [Elite Crewman](https://steamtradingcards.fandom.com/wiki/Counter-Strike:_Global_Offensive#Badges), and that is a foil badge.